# BASH: grep text in a long string

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Can anyone explain how to write a regex to get a value in a very long txt file full of meta. The whole file is without any newline separators, just a very long string, which is hard to read or analyze

I need to grep values after key username. Can anyone help? Seem to be stuck writing out a proper regex exression for this case

```
    .."somevalue\";s:7:\"text1\";s:8:\"username\";s:9:\"USER1\";s:7:\"company\";s:3:\"text2\";s:5:\  "somevalue\";s:11:\"text11\";s:8:\"username\";s:15:\"USER2\";s:7:\"company\";s:17:\"XXXX\";s:5:\...   "somevalue\";s:15:\"text110000\";s:8:\"username\";s:12:\"USER3_HERE\";s:7:\"company\";s:18:\"yyyyy\";s:
```

In the above example I need the following output

```
    USER1
    USER2
    USER3_HERE
```

Comment: If `perl` is an acceptable solution, use `perl -wn -le 'print for /\\"username\\";.*?\\"([^\\"]+)/g'`

Comment: specify format of the file. What is behind the `...` ? Are all the parts consisting in `s:<some number>:\"<some text>\";` ? then `tr` substitute `;` for newline, `grep` for output and extract the parts from within the `"` using `sed` or` cut`

Comment: Corion thanks, but the suggested code would give s:12: in output for each value instead of the usernames values

@KamilCuk it's basically a .txt file without any newline chars. Behind ... I mean that there are other different keys+values there in meta, but I only need to save ALL values of usernames, and not anything else.
Splitting would be a solution probably but the task is to not use splitting, which made me stuck

Thanks again for help

Comment: I updated my code in the meantime. If Perl is acceptable, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: That looks like PHP's `serialize()` format. Why not use PHP to parse it instead of `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl it is

```
perl -wn -le 'print for /\\"username\\";.*?\\"([^\\"]+)/g' filename
```

`-n` - process file line by line, but don't print anything

`-l` - handle line endings

`-e` - run the following code

```
print for /\\"username\\";.*?\\"([^\\"]+)/g
```

Print the captured output whenever you see `\"username\";` followed by something followed by `\"` .

#### Output

```
$ perl -wn -le 'print for /\\"username\\";.*?\\"([^\\"]+)/g'
    .."somevalue\";s:7:\"text1\";s:8:\"username\";s:9:\"USER1\";s:7:\"company\";s:3:\"text2\";s:5:\  "somevalue\";s:11:\"text11\";s:8:\"username\";s:15:\"USER2\";s:7:\"company\";s:17:\"XXXX\";s:5:\...   "somevalue\";s:15:\"text110000\";s:8:\"username\";s:12:\"USER3_HERE\";s:7:\"company\";s:18:\"yyyyy\";s:

USER1
USER2
USER3_HERE
```

#### See also

[perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the command line switches

[perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for the regular expression used

Comment: perfect! exactly what I've been looking for, and thanks for a very detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (I added the printout of the field number for clarity here with printing `i` in front of `$i`):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\\\\\""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (match($i, /USER/)) print i, $i}' file
7 USER1
18 USER2
29 USER3_HERE
```

If you want the field following those fields:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\\\\\""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (match($i, /USER/)) print $i, $(i+1)}' file
USER1 ;s:7:
USER2 ;s:7:
USER3_HERE ;s:7:
```

You can use GNU grep:

```
$ ggrep -oP 'USER[^;]*;([^\\]*)\\"company' file
USER1\";s:7:\"company
USER2\";s:7:\"company
USER3_HERE\";s:7:\"company
```

Or Perl if you just want the match group:

```
$ perl -lnE 'say for /USER[^;]*;([^\\]*)\\"company/g' file
s:7:
s:7:
s:7:
```

Comment: thanks but maybe I didn't specify correctly in my initial question

I need to grep values after username and before company. So can be not USER but anything. Basically any string can be present

Comment: Please update your question with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For the input lokking like this:

```
cat <<EOF >file
s:7:\"text1\";s:8:\"username\";s:9:\"USER1\";s:7:\"company\";s:3:\"text2\";s:5:\  "somevalue\";s:11:\"text11\";s:8:\"username\";s:15:\"USER2\";s:7:\"company\";s:17:\"XXXX\";s:5:\...   "somevalue\";s:15:\"text110000\";s:8:\"username\";s:12:\"USER3_HERE\";s:7:\"company\";s:18:\"yyyyy\";
EOF
```

We can:

```
< file \
tr ';' '\n' |
sed 's/^.*:\\"\(.*\)\\"$/\1/' |
grep -x "USER1\|USER2\|USER3_HERE"
```

- substitute the `;` for newline
- filter out the text in between the `:\"...\"`
- grep only for USER1 USER2 or USER3_HERE strings